# Вывести имя картинки на ImageButton

Tags: android

На экране есть несколько ImageButton, можно ли как-то по нажатию на любую из них выводить имя файла картинки, которая на нем установлена?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартными средствами это сделать нельзя. `ImageView` и его подклассы, в т.ч. `ImageButton` не имеют никакой информации о источнике отображаемого ими изображения.

У вас два пути:

1. Хранить самостоятельно информацию о том что и где отображено, пополняя эту информацию в момент назначения изображения в виджет.
2. Написать свою класс, коий переопределит методы отобраения картинок так, что будет в себя записывать эту информацию.